# ECS1705 which has a higher version than referenced assembly

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

My project called 'Gui Tester' has a microsoft.windowsdesktop.App.WindowsForms framework version 6.0.0. In addition, it has a project reference to WinForms class called 'WinFormsLibrary3' which its framework version 6.0.9. This causes the error below. How do I make both versions the same in order to solve this issue? I was unable to find a way to remove/add/update a framework.

A link to a sample solution (\AssemblyError\GuiTester\GuiTester.sln) can be found here - https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuZvh6FckScbhMpi02_Dm-YCBE00ew?e=KKNyLi

Error   CS1705  Assembly 'WinFormsLibrary3' with identity 'WinFormsLibrary3, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=6.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Windows.Forms' with identity 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

Comment: If you use VS2022 and recently updated it to a 17.3.x version then be sure to delete the project's .obj and .bin directories by hand.  That fixes a horrible agile bug in 17.3.0 that keeps cached build info without refreshing it.  Help > About shows the version number.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way your Gui tester project (version 6.0.0) can open your winFormsLibrary3 (version 6.0.9). Since the lower version does not recognize or support a higher version which it never designs for. What you can do is create a new solution of gui tester with a higher version and just copy all the files from the old gui tester into your new gui tester.

As I wrote in the comment, you can try downgrade your target framework, but some times it cause unexpected behaviour [image: Change the .Net target framework]
https://ourtechroom.com/fix/how-to-downgrade-net-framework-version-in-visual-studio/

Comment: There are many projects referencing winFormsLibrary3 and they all have the same error. Recreating all of them would take too much work. Is there a way to downgrade winFormsLibrary3 version or at change the GuiTester version without recreating it?

Comment: So, instead, you can create a new version of winFormLibrary3 with a lower version, but still, you will need to recreate it.

Comment: You can try downgrade it like here- https://ourtechroom.com/fix/how-to-downgrade-net-framework-version-in-visual-studio/

Comment: I don't mind recreating winFormLibrary3 however, I do not know how to control the framework version (6.0.0 instead of 6.0.9). The only options I have when creating a new project are between 5 and 6.

Comment: When you create a new project you have an option to choose which framework your solution will be. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-studio-multi-targeting-overview?view=vs-2022

Comment: I've downloaded and installed version 6.0.0 from the following link however the options I have are still 5 and 6. I cannot choose sub version such as 6.0.0 or 6.0.9 - https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0

Comment: So create winFormsLibrary3 with the framework of version 5